# RESTful web service and calling method under same application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wcf-rest

How to create a restful service and a web form application under the same solution? I want to use the same port number for both of them, something like a sub folder for one application. I have created restful using visual studio 2012 wcf and also I've created another project for calling the web service. But I feel that there are two separate application and difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api. But there will be still small difficulty with combining web forms and MVC.

Comment: can i create a web form similar restful web service?

Comment: You can look here full tutorial how to do it, I think it will help you: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms